# VS Code terminal won't show print statement output until execution is finished

Tags: visual-studio-code

Up until recently my VS Code worked fine, no problems. But now it won't show the output of print statements until all execution is finished.

[Terminal hangs after program initiation, until execution is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq2Hx.png)

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm on Windows 10, VS Code version 1.41.1. It's a machine learning application if it makes any difference, using Keras and scikit-learn.

I wouldn't be surprised if I've accidentally mashed the keyboard and triggered a hotkey setting.

```
Version: 1.41.1 (system setup)
Date: 2019-12-18T14:58:56.166Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Comment: Please don't pass code as image, paste it directly in your question using code block

Comment: Thanks Mickael - it's just a screenshot of the terminal window so you can how it looks.

Comment: Have noticed that it works fine in debug mode.